# custom objects with optional attributes as parameter in web services .net c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soapui

I'm building a webservice with C# - MVC - .Net

The webservice must return the total of registers of a table, the parameter is a custom object (ViewModel).

When consuming the webservice with SoapUi it failed if not give all parameter of the class

The code:

**ViewModel**

```
public class request
{
    public int id {get; set;}

    public string title {get; set;}

    public string description {get; set;}

    public string state {get; set;}

}
```

**Webervice**

```
[WebMethod]

public int getRequest(request req)
{
    // something
}
```

**Request generated on SoapUi**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:getRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:s>
            <tem:id>?</tem:id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:title>?</tem:title>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:description>?</tem:description>
            <tem:state>?</tem:state>
         </tem:s>
      </tem:getRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can set optional and required parameters?

why labels appear  "OPTIONAL"?

ThankS!

Answer (score 0):

Specify tag names.  I think the issue is really the tag 'tem:s'

```
    [XmlRoot("s")]
    public class request
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string description { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("state")]
        public string state { get; set; }

    }​
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persist :(

Comment: The last time I've seen this issue the person didn't put any values into the missing parameters.